# How to define custom function to generate summary stats in pydatatable?

Tags: python, py-datatable

I'm trying to build a custom function to generate a summary stats for a given field as showed in the code snippet.

```
def estadistica_dt_summario(dt,col,por):
    dt_summary= dt[{'mean_of_specific_col':mean(col),'median_of_specific_col':median(col)},by(por)]
    return dt_summary
```

Where:

- `dt` - datatable frame object
- `col` - field to be calculated (mean,median etc etc)
- `por` - field to be aggregated

Here I'm calling on the function.

```
estadistica_dt_summario(comida_dt,"co2_emission","food_category")
```

It's not working as expected and could any one of yours please let me know how to get it achieved in pydatatable way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this out:

```
def estadistica_dt_summario(DT, col, por):
    dt_summary = DT[{'mean_of_specific_col': mean(f[col]),
                     'median_of_specific_col': median(f[col])},
                    by(f[por])]
    return dt_summary
```

Remember to make use of `f` expressions when you are passing in the fields to a function